# Json, displaying the usernames

Tags: javascript, json, instagram

Using

```
var arrayOfObjects = eval(photo.likes.data);

var objects = arrayOfObjects;
console.log(objects);
```

I get the code below is what console.log echos

**json**

```
[
Object
full_name: "marcab12"
id: "181407552"
profile_picture: "http://images.instagram.com/profiles/profile_181407550_75sq_1339521398.jpg"
username: "marcab12"
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
full_name: "Ramage1992"
id: "21574723"
profile_picture: "http://images.instagram.com/profiles/profile_21574703_75sq_1349343851.jpg"
username: "ramage_1992"
__proto__: Object
]
```

How can I manage to show just the usernames on two lines as the javascipt I use seems to echo the 2 objects.

**EDIT**

```
$.each(likesperimage,function(index){
                liked = likesperimage[index].username;
                console.log(photo.id+' - '+liked);
            });
```

Comment: Don't use `eval`: use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: @lonesomeday JSON.parse is not available in older IE.

Comment: @Shusl - For older browsers, it is better to include *json2.js* available from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js - which has implementations for `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that this is a json array and you want to display the username for all the users in this array.The following code should work

```
        $.each(arrayOfObjects,function(index)
        {
           console.log(arrayOfObjects[index].username);              

        });
```

here is the link to each in jquery api
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Please test this code before using it.This is just a demonstration of how it can be done and there might be better ways to do it.

Comment: it displays on each line but when I try the edit in my code it only shows the last username.

Comment: That is because you are storing it inside a variable and accessing the value of the variable after the loop is run.

Comment: how can I alter that to do what I need?

Comment: Well you could edit the items inside the loop and push it in an array this way you will have access to the edited items after the loop is finished.check out this link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp